# Set nautilus to manage only desktop

Tags: nautilus

I replaced nautilus with nemo file manager, because i like it much more, but nemo cant handle wallpapers in desktop. How can i set nautilus to manage desktop only? I dont want to have nautilus "files" in dash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nautilus as part of the GNOME desktop applications is deeply integrated into the system.

Removing the Files entry from dash in any way is not recommended (reason : see above).

Change the Ubuntu Unity desktop background from within system settings alternatively.

You can disable or enable search of files with the Unity Tweak Tool from the repositories.

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

Open the tool - click on Search

[image]

Additionally you can disable files and application usage recording in the system settings.